# How to Convert 28V to 12V?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, schematics

I have to use a 28V DC power supply for a certain design I am doing. But I only need 12V DC to power up this device. How would I design this in a schematic? What would I need? I have been searching up DC/DC converters...but I am not sure if I am on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: You are on the right track, at least if you're not powering motors.  You can get pre-made modules, or you can get chips and design a buck converter into your board.

Comment: LM2596 is a popular switching chip for upto 2A. MC34063 is a popular low cost chip for upto 500mA. If you need low noise, consider dropping to 15V with the switcher, and then use a linear regulator (LM317, LM7812, AMS1117-ADJ or similar). As Tim says, pre-made modules are available for the LM2596. Otherwise, datasheets have info for PCB layout.

Comment: First lay out your specifications. You know you want to go from 28V to 12V ...but at what current?

Answer (score 1):

One way to design this into a schematic is through use of online tools such as those provided by Analog Devices, TI, and others.  Here are two links that might help:  https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/ltpowercad.html   http://www.ti.com/tools-software/design-center/webench-power-designer.html

After you get a schematic together post back here with further questions.

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on required current and efficiency. 
If current is low and efficiency is of no value, use linear regulator (for example 7812). If current is high and big heat sink is tolerable, linear regulator may be used too. Otherwise use DC/DC converter. It will be smaller, much more efficient, complex and expensive.